Generate Quasi Random Numbers for a Multivariate DIstribution
Algorithms like Sobol or Holton provide quasi random numbers (that is, the numbers "look" random in the sense of a uniform distribution, but they are deterministic) in the hypercube $[0,1]^d$. Let $$x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$$ be a sequence of such pseuo random numbers. For any distribution function $F$ of a particular distribution (say, a normal distribution), $$F^{-1}(x_1), F^{-1}(x_2), ..., F^{-1}(x_n)$$ are quasi random numbers distributed according to $F$.
If $F$ is the distribution function of a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma$, then $$F^{-1}(x_i) = C\Phi^{-1}(x_i) + \mu,$$ where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the quantile function of a standard normal function applied componentwise to the vector $x_i$ and $C$ is the Cholesky decomposition of $\Sigma$. That is, I can easily generate quasi random vectors with a multivariate normal distribution.
Now I want to generate quasi random vectors with a multivariate t distribution. One can generate random vectors that have a multivariate t distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom by $$\sqrt{\frac{k}{\chi_i}}C\Phi^{-1}(x_i) + \mu,$$ where $\chi_i$ is a chi-squared distributed random variable with $k$ degrees of freedom. By setting $\chi_i = \mathcal X^{-1}_k(y_i)$ with $\mathcal X^{-1}_k$ denoting the quantile function of a chi-squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom. What is $y$? Well, this is exactly my question. The problem is if I chose, say, the first element of $x_i$ for $y_i$, then $y_i$ and $x_i$ are obviously no longer independent, contradicting the algorithm for generating random numbers with a multivariate t distribution. Of course, I could just chose an $i$ at random and a $j$ (the component) at random, but then I could just generate random numbers in the first place, which I don't want (this problem is part of an integration problem with importance sampling). An obvious solution is to compute $F^{-1}(x_i)$ directly. However, $F^{-1}$ has no closed form and is thus difficult to approximate.
Are there any other solutions that may help me achive what I want?

Use a [tag:copula].

Inverting a multivariate cdf does not return the correct distribution, see eg https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/449759/7224

Thanks you for your replies. It seems like the solution provided in the other questions is the conditional distribution method used in copulas for random number generation.

Note that using the inverse cdf transform in a multivariate setting is both undefined (because it can be defined in many ways) and incorrect (because it would not return a generation from the proper distribution). One (possibly possible) way to keep using the inverse cdf transform is to generate one component of the vector at a time and use the cumulated conditional inverse cdf transforms, i.e.
$$X_1=F_1(U_1)\,, X_2=F_{2|1}(U_2|X_1)\,,\ X_3=F_{3|12}(U_3|X_1,X_2)\,,$$
and so on, assuming all cdf inverses can be computed.
When generating once the multivariate $t$ as
$$\sqrt{\frac{k}{\chi}}C\Phi^{-1}(x) + \mu,$$
the chi-squared $\chi$ random variable and the standard multivariate Normal random vector $x$ are independent.
When generating an iid sample from the multivariate $t$, one must use
$$\sqrt{\frac{k}{\chi_i}}C\Phi^{-1}(x_i) + \mu,$$
with the chi-squared $\chi_i$ random variables and the standard multivariate Normal random vectors $x_i$ between them and across simulations. In other words, a new ${\chi_i}$ need be simulated for each index $i$ or equivalently a new and independent standard univariate Normal random variable $y_i$ must be generated for each $i$ (with $\chi_i = \mathcal X^{-1}_k(y_i)$)

Thanks for pointing this out. I modified the subscript accordingly. However, what you mention in your last sentecen is exactly my problem: I have a $n\times d$ matrix of quasi random numbers. I use them to create standard normal random variables. But then I have no quasi ranom variables left. So I thought about recycling the random numbers from the matrix to generate chi-squared random variables. But then the standard normals and the chi-squared quasi random variables are no longer independent.

@Quertiopler: I do not understand the constraint on the number of quasi-random draws, but if it is a hard constraint, you need set aside some of them for the chi-squared random variables in order to preserve independence. Obviously, if $n\times d$ is large, picking at random from the table an additional $n$ times to generate the $n$ chi-squared random variables should not induce much dependence in the final sample.
